# How to find rows of a matrix where with the same ordering of unique and duplicated elements, but not necessarily the same value

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I wasn't quite sure how to phrase this question. Suppose I have the following matrix:

```
A=[1 0 0;
   0 0 1;
   0 1 0;
   0 1 1;
   0 1 2;
   3 4 4]
```

Given row 1, I want to find all rows where:

- the elements that are unique in row 1, are unique in the same column in the other row, but don't necessarily have the same value
- and if there are elements with duplicate values in row 1, there are be duplicate values in the same columns in the other row, but not necessarily the same value

For example, in matrix A, if I was given row 1 I would like to find rows 4 and 6.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524077/how-to-determine-if-two-partitions-clusterings-of-data-points-are-identical. Use the proposed methods for each line of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Can't test this right now, but I think the following will work:

```
A=[1 0 0;
   0 0 1;
   0 1 0;
   0 1 1;
   0 1 2;
   3 4 4];

B = zeros(size(A));

for ii = 1:size(A,1)
  r = A(ii,:);
  B(ii,1) = 1;
  for jj = 2:size(A,2)
    c = find(r(1:jj-1)==r(jj));
    if numel(c) > 0
      B(ii,jj) = B(ii,c);
    else
      B(ii,jj) = B(ii,jj-1)+1;
    end
  end
end
```

At the end of this we have an array B in which "like indices have like values" and the rows you are looking for are now identical.

Now you can do

```
[C, ia, ic] = unique(B,'rows','stable');
disp('The answer you want is ');
disp(ia);
```

And the answer you want will be in the variable `ia`. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html#btb0_8v . I am not 100% sure that you can use the `rows` and `stable` parameters in the same call - but I think you can.

Try it and see if it works - and ask questions if you need more info.

Comment: update - meant to call `unique(B,'rows','stable')` - not `A`... Is that better?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method

```
B = NaN(size(A)); %//Preallocation

for row = 1:size(A,1)
    [~,~,B(row,:)] = unique(A(row,:), 'stable');
end

find(ismember(B(2:end,:), B(1,:), 'rows')) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution without loops:

```
row = 1; %// row used as reference
equal = bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(A, [1 3 2]));
equal = reshape(equal,size(A,1),[]); %// linearized signature of each row
result = find(ismember(equal,equal(row,:),'rows')); %// find matching rows
result = setdiff(result,row); %// remove reference row, if needed
```

The key is to compute a "signature" of each row, meaning the equality relationship between all combinations of its elements. This is done with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). Then, rows with the same signature can be easily found with [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Floris. The unique call didn't work correctly and I think you meant to use matrix B in it, too. Here's what I managed to do, although it's not as clean:

```
A=[1 0 0 1;
   0 0 1 3;
    0 1 0 1;
    0 1 1 0;
    0 1 2 2;
    3 4 4 3;
    5 9 9 4];

 B = zeros(size(A));

 for ii = 1:size(A,1) 
   r = A(ii,:); 
   B(ii,1) = 1; 
   for jj = 2:size(A,2) 
      c = find(r(1:jj-1)==r(jj)); 
     if numel(c) > 0 
       B(ii,jj) = B(ii,c);
     else
         B(ii,jj) = max(B(ii,:))+1; % need max to generalize to more columns
     end
   end
 end

 match = zeros(size(A,1)-1,size(A,2));
 for i=2:size(A,1)
     for j=1:size(A,2)
         if B(i,j) == B(1,j)
             match(i-1,j)=1;
         end
     end
 end

 index=find(sum(match,2)==size(A,2));
```

In the nested loops I check if the elements in the rows below it match up in the correct column. If there is a perfect match the row should sum to the row dimension.

When I generalize this for the specific problem I'm working on the matrix fills with a certain set of base size(A,2) numbers. So for base 4 and greater, a max statement is needed in the else statement for no matches. Otherwise, for certain number combinations in a given row, a duplication of an element may occur when there is none.

Answer (score 0):

A overview would be to reduce each row into a "signature" counting element repeats, i.e., your row 1 becomes 1, 2. Then check for equal signatures.

Comment: Well, that's more or less what I did :-) Also, note that something like "1,2" is not valid as a signature. For example, a row like `1 0 0 2` and `1 0 0 1` would both give a "1,2,1" signature, when their structure is different