# Evaluate Image Segmentation Method

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have segmented an image using an algorithm into the following labels 
This will be a 4 x 4 matrix of labels if it is reshaped. Using the lists below as an example:

```py
imagesegment = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3]
groundtruth =  [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,3]
```

Given the ground truth and the segmentation above all containing labels with different labeling schemes, how can I evaluate the method?

```py
def jaccard_similarity(list1, list2):
    s1 = set(list1)
    s2 = set(list2)
    return len(s1.intersection(s2)) / len(s1.union(s2))


jaccard(imagesegment, groundtruth)
```

Given that the labeling scheme are not the same as shown above how best can the segmented image be compared with the ground-truth?

Note From comparing the lists: 1 in image segment can be seen as 2 in ground-truth, 2 as 3 and  3 as 1.  So it is not misclassifications but use of different labeling.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15524077/1714410

Comment: @venkata I have heard of dice coefficient. But i think it has the same problem  just as Jaccard. As they perform set operations on the lists. Correct me if I am wrong OK!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to compare the co-occurrence matrics.

The partition co-occurrence matrix is `n`x`n` (where `n` is the number of points, 16 in your case) binary matrix where

```
C_ij = 1 iff label(i) == label(j)
```

You can compute the co-occurence matrix for `imagesegment` and for `groundtruth` and count the number of identical entries.

```py
imagesegment = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3])
groundtruth =  np.array([2,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,3])
Ci = imagesegment[None, :] == imagesegment[:, None]
Cg = groundtruth[None, :] == groundtruth[:, None]
# compare only half the matrix and ignore diagonal 
fci = np.concatenate([np.diag(Ci,k=k) for k in range(1, 16)])
fcg = np.concatenate([np.diag(Cg, k=k) for k in range(1, 16)])
# the actual score:
(fci==fcg).mean()  # 0.775 in your case. score of 1 is perfect
```

Comment: This seems to be a good way of comparing. Is there a general name for this technique(just like Jacard, dice, F1)?